# Excel Match Values from column and check date in two columns with greater or less than

Tags: excel, date, indexing, match, vlookup

A   (licence)   B (Licence Expiry)   C (Licence)     D (Licence Changed)

HI,

So my aim here is to compare column A with Column C and find matches if match found check corresponding date from column B (date) and check column D to see if column D (date) is greater than or less than and return value in cell E
I hope that makes send, i have tried vlookup and looked at index and match but not sure what meets my requirements.

Thanks

Comment: Are you expecting just one match in column C or could there be more?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply im expecting on match the compare is a unique value (licence key)- Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if an ordinary VLOOKUP would be fine

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(A2,C:D,2,FALSE)<=B2,"Not expired","Expired"),"No match")
```

or an INDEX/MATCH

```
=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(D:D,MATCH(A2,C:C,0))<=B2,"Not expired","Expired"),"No match")
```